# How can I create this pattern in moderncv classic

Tags: moderncv

[image]

I am wondering about creating something like this in `moderncv`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far (can you show us that in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? Doesn't the template come with an example file that shows how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I create something exactly like this in modernCv?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337008/how-can-i-create-something-exactly-like-this-in-moderncv)

Answer (score 3):

This just looks like a nested `itemize` i.e.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Programming Languages and Frameworks
    \begin{itemize}
        \item C++,java
        \item SQL
    \end{itemize}
    \item Analytical Modelers and Simulators
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Maple and Matlab
        \item AMPL
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Or in a minimal example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\name{user}{delsa}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Programming Languages and Frameworks
    \begin{itemize}
        \item C++,java
        \item SQL
    \end{itemize}
    \item Analytical Modelers and Simulators
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Maple and Matlab
        \item AMPL
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]