# how can I create something exactly like this in modernCv?

Tags: moderncv

[image]

I want to create something like this in modernCv, how I can create a section in latex for that. please, pay attention that i want produce space at the left exactly like picture that i have posted.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Agree with Dai Bowen. Exactly same question, probably same OP with different user account as well.

Comment: really, I saw the answers, but I want to shift the content. in the proposed answer, the options under skill have started from end left, but I want to put those under the skill, exactly like the picture.

Comment: I want to produce something exactly like the above picture. please help me if you can?

Comment: @delsa OK, if the answers don't meet your specifications then comment on them to communicate that (you could also consider editing your question to try and make it clearer). Starting a new question which asks for the same thing is not really helpful and doesn't mean users won't miss part of your specification if it is unclear. Also please do note moewe's comment on that question, we love [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and seeing what you've tried so far on this site, this normally helps us understand what is desired.

Comment: I am working in a sample cv of  (https://www.sharelatex.com), and i want to change one cv in that site to produce my desirable cv.

Comment: @delsa Please help us to help you and give us a few information. Which "sample cv" are you working with? There are many versions floating around. Where shall the blue line be located? Should it reach into the margin? Should it left align with the text? The "Skills" and the itemize symbols are not aligned in your image, is this on purpose?

Comment: the bellow answer is what that I was looking for it. I am working on this https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-classic and I think bellow answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{user}{delsa}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{align=left, leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+ separatorcolumnwidth+\leftmargini}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Programming Languages and Frameworks
    \begin{itemize}
        \item C++,java
        \item SQL
    \end{itemize}
    \item Analytical Modelers and Simulators
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Maple and Matlab
        \item AMPL
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you prefer the texts of the item and of the section title to begin at the same point. For that just use

```
\setlist[itemize, 1]{align=left, leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+separatorcolumnwidth}
```

[image]

Comment: I already have a command, \usepackage[scale=0.75, scale=0.8, left=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry} I think this has conflict with your command for margin.

Comment: I don't think so: `enumitem` has nothing to do with `geometry`. But your choice of parameters for geometry are inconsistent: you have two different `scale=…`. Further, you can't choose at  the same time  values for `hscale`, `left` and `right`. You certainly have warnings, perhaps errors, on compiling.